# Propagate async PointCollection change to UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm

I am having trouble propagating the result of asynchronnous method to the UI.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="COVMin.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:COVMin"        
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="170">
        <Polygon Points="{Binding Points}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Opacity="0.8" />
    </Border>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Marin="0,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Command="{Binding DrawPointsCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{        
    private PointCollection points { get; set; }

    public PointCollection Points
    {
        get { return this.points; }
        set
        {                
            this.points = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Points");
        }
    }

    public ICommand DrawPointsCommand { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simplified, in real it´s long time operation causing UI to freeze.
    /// </summary>        
    private Task<PointCollection> ConvertToPointCollection()
    {
        return Task.Run<PointCollection>(() =>
        {
            PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
            points.Add(new System.Windows.Point(0, 6236832));                
            points.Add(new System.Windows.Point(255, 6236832));

            return points;
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private async Task<PointCollection> Process()
    {            
        this.Points = await ConvertToPointCollection();
        return this.Points;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method calling long-time operation bound to button as a Command.
    /// </summary>
    private async void GetValues()
    {
        this.Points = await Process();            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.DrawPointsCommand = new DelegateCommand(GetValues);
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for PropertyChanged event handling.
    /// </summary>        
    class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {  
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

DelegateCommand class

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{        
    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;        
}
```

The problem is with OnPropertyChange, which causes System.ArgumentException telling me that I have to create DependencySource on the same thread as DependencyObject. I have spend quite some hours trying with Dispatchers and what not but still no good.

Comment: _"telling me that I have to create DependencySource on the same thread as DependencyObject"_ -- which you do. Technically, that makes your question a duplicate of the canonical "use Dispatcher" answer. That said, your question is too vague to know for sure that's all the help you need. With the `Task`-based method, you should be able to `await` the result and avoid explicit interaction with the `Dispatcher` object. But your code example above doesn't even show how `Process()` is called. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the example above, but I am not sure what else should I put there.

Comment: The article at the link I provided in the previous comment provides all of the information you need to know "what else should you put there".

Comment: Thank you, I simplified the problem as much as possible ending with 3 classes and XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `PointCollection` is a `DependencyObject` and so is owned by the thread that creates it. Normally, you cannot use such objects in other threads. Using `Dispatcher` (explicitly, or implicitly with `await` as your code example does) wouldn't help here, because it's not the UI thread that owns the object. Indeed, it's trying to use that object on the UI thread that causes the problem.

There is an important exception though to the "no sharing across threads" rule, for `DependencyObjects` that are also `Freezable` objects, as `PointCollection` is. If you freeze the object in the owning thread before any other thread tries to access it, then it is safe to use in other threads.

So you can change your `ConvertToPointCollection()` method to look like this:

```
private Task<PointCollection> ConvertToPointCollection()
{
    return Task.Run<PointCollection>(() =>
    {
        PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
        points.Add(new System.Windows.Point(0, 6236832));                
        points.Add(new System.Windows.Point(255, 6236832));

        points.Freeze();

        return points;
    });
}
```

Of course, this will also prevent the object from being modified later. If you need to be able to modify the collection, then you will have to take a different approach. For example, create the `PointCollection` in the UI thread, and then use an intermediate type (like `List<Point>`) to pass new points from your background thread to the UI thread, where the UI thread can then copy those points into the `PointCollection`.